# What were the first areas of research and what were some early successes?

Tags: history

What were the first areas of research into Artificial Intelligence and what were some early successes?  More recently we've had:

1. Beating a human at the game of chess
2. Convincing a human that a person was conversing with them (passing the Turing test)
3. Beating a human at Jeopardy game show
4. Beating a human at the game of go.

Were there milestones that were considered major in the field before the 1990s?

Answer (score 4):

What might be classed as AI has of course changed over the years, but landmarks and research breakthroughs include:

- Babbagge's [Difference Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine) (~1823) for tabulating/interpolating polynomials.
- Frank Rosenblatt's 1957 invention of the [Perceptron](http://blogs.umass.edu/brain-wars/files/2016/03/rosenblatt-1957.pdf).
- John McCarthy's invention of [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)) in the late 1950s.
- Arthur Samuel's 1959 [checkers player](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-30668-1_9), which famously improved by playing against itself (it would have been nice if that had destroyed the myth about a program only being as 'intelligent' as its creator).
- Newell and Simon's 1959 [General Problem Solver](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/rand/ipl/P-1584_Report_On_A_General_Problem-Solving_Program_Feb59.pdf) applied Means-Ends analysis to solve a range of problems expressed as Horn clauses.
- Davis, Putnam et al: 1962 invention of the [DPLL algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm) which still forms the core of modern SAT-based theorem provers.
- Lawrence Fogel et al: 1966 book [Artificial Intelligence through Simulated Evolution](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000CNARU).
- Rechenberg and Schwefel: 1960s development of [Evolutionsstrategie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_strategy) - an Evolutionary Computation approach using mutation and a form of Darwinian 'survival of the fittest'.
- Lotfi Zadeh's 1965 invention of [Fuzzy Logic](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~zadeh/papers/Fuzzy%20Sets-Information%20and%20Control-1965.pdf).
- John Holland's 1975 book ["Adaptation in Natural and Artificial Systems"](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=531075) which introduced Genetic Algorithms.
- The 1980 [Hearsay II](http://aitopics.org/sites/default/files/classic/Webber-Nilsson-Readings/Rdgs-NW-Erman-Hayes-Roth-Lesser-Reddy.pdf) Blackboard Architecture by Hayes-Roth et al.
- The 1980s invention of the [backpropagation algorithm](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=104293) for Mutlilayer Perceptrons by Rumelhart, Hinton et al.

Comment: Flying a bit under the radar, but nonetheless relevant, (you know, neural networks, improving by self-play, introduces completely new strategies, etc.): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TD-Gammon